# OpenCSV - parse collection in header

Tags: groovy, redmine, opencsv

I have a working setup (btw. using groovy) for OpenCSV HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy and MyCustomBean.

```groovy
def file = new FileReader(new File("sample.csv"))
def csvReader = new CSVReader(file)
def strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MyCustomBean>()
strategy.setType(MyCustomBean)
```

I am curious, whether it is possible to parse any collection (I guess a map) from header.

Sample csv

```
priority,subject,description,customFields[4]
1,first,foo,X-7
2,second,hoo,X-8
```

Mapped bean

```groovy
class MyCustomBean {
    def subject
    def description
    def priority
    def customFields
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example csv?

Comment: @tim_yates I have edited the question. I am preparing an import script for Redmine, which has custom fields as a map.